# Hugo site using blogdown : tag links are broken

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I created a new blog using R's blogdown package. I have a problem with the tags though. I get redirected to the relative path rather (eg: https://tags/tag-name).

Any idea how can I fix this?

- Reproducible example in r: `blogdown::new_site(theme = 'halogenica/beautifulhugo')`
- Blog link: https://d-notebook.github.io/

Comment: You may not realize it is a duplicate but it is essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/48414410/559676.