# Control index.xml for Atom/RSS to generate valid rss feed (without relative links)

Tags: r, rss, hugo, blogdown

**Task:** I want to add an RSS feed to my site. (Later I want to add a separate RSS feed for a specific category [for R Bloggers])

**Setup:**

- I use the Hugo Academic template
- via the R blogdown package
- push my sources to github 
  https://github.com/Tazinho/AlmostRandom
- from where it gets published via netlify
  http://www.malte-grosser.com/
- added an example blogpost here
  http://www.malte-grosser.com/post/test-post/

**Issue and validation:**

1. According to this video
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF0tohv99Ow
   my blogs rss should be this
   http://www.malte-grosser.com/index.xml
2. According to some validator side 
   http://www.feedvalidator.org/
   My rss feed seems not to be valid and has several kinds of errors
   http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.malte-grosser.com%2Findex.xml
   eg: line 5, column 11: link must be a full and valid URL: / [help]

**Steps to solve this so far:**

- I followed some SO posts, as far as I could. For example this related one

  - [Control index.xml for Atom/RSS (hugo / blogdown generates feed with relative links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414410/control-index-xml-for-atom-rss-hugo-blogdown-generates-feed-with-relative-lin)
- I added rss.xml to /post/layouts/ and modified it according to

  - https://coolbutuseless.bitbucket.io/2018/02/07/blogdown-rss-feed-of-full-articles/
  - I struggled a bit with the part under 
    "# Reference your RSS Feed". I don't know wehre exactly what exactly has to go
  - I read several other posts and tried to find similar public repositories from rbind.io.
  - I deleted most of my trials, to have a clean setup for further trials
- the only parts I kept are the following changes within config.toml

  - baseurl = "http://malte-grosser.com/"
  - rssLimit = 10
  - `[outputs]
         home = [ "HTML", "CSS", "RSS" ]
         section = [ "HTML", "RSS" ]
         taxonomy = [ "HTML", "RSS" ]
         taxonomyTerm = [ "HTML", "RSS" ]`
  - and the rss.xml under /post/layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding (after reading once more [Control index.xml for Atom/RSS (hugo / blogdown generates feed with relative links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414410/control-index-xml-for-atom-rss-hugo-blogdown-generates-feed-with-relative-lin)) it seems to be ok to have these kind of errors.

Also for anyone with similar problems: It turns out that the blogs RSS should be under http://www.malte-grosser.com/post/index.xml and the categories RSS's should be under http://www.malte-grosser.com/categories/R-bloggers/index.xml